# Need the smallest font in node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need the smallest font. How can I set font size smaller than `\fontsize{1}{1}`?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \draw[-{Latex[length=1mm,width=1mm]}] (-0.1,0) -- (2.3,0) node[right] {\tiny $x$};
  \draw[-{Latex[length=1mm,width=1mm]}] (0,-0.1) -- (0,1.6) node[above] {\tiny$f(x)$};
  \node[font=\fontsize{1}{1}\selectfont] at (1.2,1.2) [below]{$x_0$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just don't.  Nobody will be able to read that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can scale down the node including the text using `transform shape` and `scale`.  I don't see the point though.  Nobody will be able to read that on a printout.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[font=\tiny,transform shape,scale=0.1] {$X_0$};
  \node{O};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You do not need `transform shape` if the `scale` is in the node style.

Answer (score 4):

You need the package fix-cm if you want that 1pt fontsize is really 1pt:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \draw[-{Latex[length=1mm,width=1mm]}] (-0.1,0) -- (2.3,0) node[right] {\tiny $x$};
  \draw[-{Latex[length=1mm,width=1mm]}] (0,-0.1) -- (0,1.6) node[above] {\tiny$f(x)$};
  \node[font=\fontsize{1}{1}\selectfont] at (1.2,1.2) [below]{$x_0$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also use values smaller than 1pt.